# MVC entity sql insert error when registering user

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new to MVC and cant quite figure this out. I am using the Login template provided by microsoft but I am trying to write only the user email to another database separate from the aspnetusers database. The following code gives me an error

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel useremail)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = useremail.Email, Email = useremail.Email };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, useremail.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {

                    //await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);
                    using (myEntities entities = new myEntities())
                    {
                        entities.users.Add(useremail.Email);

                    }


                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(useremail);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to add users in your separate user table which required a user model (entity class), but you are passing only email address at mention below a line.

```
  entities.users.Add(useremail.Email);
```

Comment: All I want to pass is email

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this :

**entities.users.Add(useremail.Email);**

And Add this:

**entities.users.Add(user);**

Comment: Use this : entities.users.Add(user);